# Error when calling custom DLL in CodeUnit: Request for WebPermission failed

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I came by this error when coding in Dynamics NAV CodeUnit and calling my own custom DLL. It took some time to figure out what was the problem. Se my own answer...

"Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=' failed"

Answer (score 0):

Problem was Windows blocking downloaded files. Doh!

For each downloaded file:

- Right click
- Properties
- Unblock
- Save

Creating this answer for other to find on the internet.